# How do I parse .obj files with C++ on OpenGL (e.g. using libobj or another library)?

Tags: opengl, blender

I am trying to use `libobj` to parse a `.obj` file exported from Blender.
The website http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~ares.lagae/libobj/index.html
is where I got `libobj` from and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_Object_file_format
describes the ins and outs of the `.obj` file format. The `libobj` website
has an example on how to parse vertices which I have elaborated in the
following code.

However I am unsure about how to parse faces and render
them in OpenGL. Do I have to use vertex lists or server side buffer objects?
How can I expand on the code below to get it to render the faces properly?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <obj.hpp>
#include <iostream>

    void geometric_vertex_callback(obj::float_type x, obj::float_type y, obj::float_type z)
    {
      std::cout << "v " << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }

    void display() {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      obj::obj_parser obj_parser;
      obj_parser.geometric_vertex_callback(geometric_vertex_callback);
      std::cout << std::endl;
      glLoadIdentity();
      gluLookAt(1.0f, 1.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      obj_parser.parse("./cube.obj");
      glEnd();
      glFlush();

    }

    void reshape(int h, int w) {

      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glOrtho(-8.0f, 8.0f, -8.0f, 8.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f);
      glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
      glutCreateWindow("cube");
      glutDisplayFunc(display);
      glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
      glutMainLoop();
      return 0;
    }
```

---

Compile with: `g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lobj`

Answer (score 3):

Check the reference (http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~ares.lagae/libobj/obj-0.1/doc/html/classobj_1_1obj__parser.html). There are multiple callbacks you can use in order to render your geometry.

.OBJ is a pretty simple and straightforward format. I think it's not that difficult writing a parser and it might be an interesting learning experience.

Comment: Thanks, it appears to me that I need to use the following callback to render the vertices: http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~ares.lagae/libobj/obj-0.1/doc/html/classobj_1_1obj__parser.html    There are many callbacks coded in post 2007 standard C++ documented, I'm trying to at least set them up (a function that takes 20 callbacks as arguments).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not exactly the question you were asking since you want to use libobj, but I find it much better to learn how to do something myself than use a premade library. I actually just finished implementing a simple .obj reader for my program. I will post it here to get you started.

*Please note that it contains some code which is specific to my implementation (i.e. how I handle my vertex buffers, etc), and it still only handles object files with a single object in it.* But hopefully this will set you on the right track.

Also, I followed a tutorial I found online (can't remember which), so I can not take all credit for this.

```
private class Face{
    public int[] v;
    public int[] vt;
    public int[] vn;

    public Face(){
        v = new int[3];
        vt = new int[3];
        vn = new int[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            v[i] = vt[i] = vn[i] = -1;
        }
    }
}

public void readObjFile(String fileName){
    Reader r;
    try{
        r = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);
        String line = null;
        int lineNo = 0;
        float[] floatTemp = new float[3];
        int[] intTemp = new int[3];

        ArrayList<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();
        ArrayList<Vector3> v = new ArrayList<Vector3>();
        ArrayList<Vector2> vt = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
        ArrayList<Vector3> vn = new ArrayList<Vector3>();

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            ++lineNo;

            String[] elements = line.split("\\s+");

            if(elements.length > 0){
                if(elements[0].equals("v")){
                    if(elements.length < 4){
                        System.out.println("Something is wrong with the obj loading");
                    }
                    else{
                        //mVertexBuffer.addVertex(new Vector3(Float.parseFloat(elements[1]), Float.parseFloat(elements[2]),Float.parseFloat(elements[3])));
                        v.add(new Vector3(Float.parseFloat(elements[1]), Float.parseFloat(elements[2]),Float.parseFloat(elements[3])));
                    }
                }
                else if(elements[0].equals("vt")){
                    if(elements.length < 3){
                        System.out.println("Something is wrong with the obj loading");
                    }
                    else{
                        //mVertexBuffer.addTextureCoord(new Vector2(Float.parseFloat(elements[1]), Float.parseFloat(elements[2])));
                        vt.add(new Vector2(Float.parseFloat(elements[1]), 1.0f - Float.parseFloat(elements[2])));
                    }
                }
                else if(elements[0].equals("vn"))
                {
                    if(elements.length < 4){
                        System.out.println("Something is wrong with the obj loading");
                    }
                    else{
                        //mVertexBuffer.addVertex(new Vector3(Float.parseFloat(elements[1]), Float.parseFloat(elements[2]),Float.parseFloat(elements[3])));
                        vn.add(new Vector3(Float.parseFloat(elements[1]), Float.parseFloat(elements[2]),Float.parseFloat(elements[3])));
                    }
                }
                else if(elements[0].equals("f")){
                    if(elements.length != 4){
                        System.out.println("Something is wrong with the obj loading");
                    }
                    else{
                        //if(mIndexBuffer == null){
                        //  mIndexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(mGl);
                        //}

                        Face newFace = new Face();

                        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                            String seg = elements[i];

                            if(seg.indexOf("/") > 0) 
                            {
                                String[] faceOrder = seg.split("/");

                                if (faceOrder.length > 0) {
                                    //mIndexBuffer.addIndex(Integer.valueOf(faceOrder[0]) - 1);
                                    newFace.v[i - 1] = Integer.valueOf(faceOrder[0]) - 1;
                                }

                                if (faceOrder.length > 1) {
                                    if(faceOrder[1].length() > 0){
                                        //f.uvIndices.add(Integer.valueOf(faceOrder[1]));
                                        newFace.vt[i - 1] = Integer.valueOf(faceOrder[1]) - 1;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (faceOrder.length > 2) {
                                    //f.normalIndices.add(Integer.valueOf(faceOrder[2]));
                                    newFace.vn[i - 1] = Integer.valueOf(faceOrder[2]) - 1;
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (seg.length() > 0) {
                                    //mIndexBuffer.addIndex(Integer.valueOf(seg) - 1);
                                    newFace.v[i - 1] = Integer.valueOf(seg) - 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        faces.add(newFace);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Now do post process
        for(int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++){
            mVertexBuffer.addVertex(v.get(faces.get(i).v[0]));
            mVertexBuffer.addVertex(v.get(faces.get(i).v[1]));
            mVertexBuffer.addVertex(v.get(faces.get(i).v[2]));
            if(vt.size() > 0){
                mVertexBuffer.addTextureCoord(vt.get(faces.get(i).vt[0]));
                mVertexBuffer.addTextureCoord(vt.get(faces.get(i).vt[1]));
                mVertexBuffer.addTextureCoord(vt.get(faces.get(i).vt[2]));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I notice you are using Java (JOGL?) instead of C++. I have not got a reference on JOGL although I will soon need to get to grips with it since eventually I need to port my code to android. Now I'm contemplating learning JOGL instead and using the min3d library. Anyhow, I'm stil trying to code that long function in libobj without making any mistake so I at least don't get any compile time errors.

Comment: Can I use an IDE to fill out the functions for me?           obj_parser.face_callbacks(
            triangular_face_geometric_vertices_callback_type,
            triangular_face_geometric_vertices_texture_vertices_callback,
            triangular_face_geometric_vertices_vertex_normals_callback,
            triangular_face_geometric_vertices_texture_vertices_vertex_normals_callback, etc..

I am having some trouble copying all of these one by one. Can I use an IDE which will allow me to do this quickly?

Comment: Yes I am using JOGl, but the principles should be the same for obj loading. I am not sure what you mean by having an IDE fill out the functions for you, like autocomplete, or actually create the functions and the code?

Comment: Yes, I mean like autocomplete. Anyways, I have just tried installing JOGL on Ubuntu Linux 11.10. I have followed all the instructions found on the following page: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/HowToBuild.html and I cannot even compile the quad example from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL . I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I installed OpenJDK instead of gcj so it should work fine, but I get the error: JOGLQuad.java:8: package javax.media.opengl does not exist
import javax.media.opengl.GL;
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong. Why can't I install JOGL properly?

Comment: You don't seem to have javax.media.opengl in a location that can be found by your java installation. Try making sure that the paths ar eset up correctly. I have never tried to run JOGL with ubuntu, so I can't help you much there. I suggest making a separate question to address this problem.

Comment: OK, I have solved part of the problem. I had to add $HOME/jogamp/jogl/build/jogl/classes to my CLASSPATH variable (I created the jogamp directory under $HOME in fact, before getting its subdirectories with git and building). With this change I can compile. However, even when I add . to the CLASSPATH and export it I cannot run the compiled bytecode. I get the following: $ java JOGLQuad
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/nativewindow/WindowClosingProtocol
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)